# Picasa android integration

Tags: android, picasa

Can any one please suggest me best way of integrating Picasa in Android application? i have try a lot but not get any proper documentation..?

I have been used Picsasa web album for java . but it store the user credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will possible by using **gdata** Api of google for Picasa.

I was found use full API over here.

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the libs that I used. Extract them to your_project_path/war/WEB-INF/lib/ and then in your Build Path, add all of them as JARs.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/0r3tcradaklrgju/Downloads.zip

I've done with it on Ubuntu 12.04, with ADT Bundle (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522). After a few Refreshes, Close/Opens... It finally worked.